# Use Date difference in a where clause with SQL

Tags: sql, date

From a table named 'Subscriptions' I want to list all item that expire between 0 and 3 days from the current day.

```
$Today = date('Y-m-d');

|--------|----------|------------|
| SUB_Id | SUB_Name | SUB_End    |
|--------|----------|------------|
| 1      | Banana   | 2017-12-01 |
| 2      | Apple    | 2017-11-03 |
| 3      | Pear     | 2017-11-03 |
|--------|----------|------------|
```

I should have the last two rows as the `SUB_End` - `$Today` is <= 3 days.

What I try:

```
select * from Subscriptions
where DATEDIFF(SUB_End , $today) <= 3;
```

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: `datediff()` is non-standard SQL. Which database product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this entirely in SQL:

```
select s.*
from Subscriptions s
where sub_end >= curdate() and
      sub_end <= curdate() + interval 3 day;
```

Comment: Interesting. How can I get the difference if I need to use it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. 
Edited: Oracle based solution.

```
select s.*
from Subscriptions s
where s.sub_end BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Comment: You should mention that this is an Oracle specific solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query, this is only for sql server :

```
select * from Subscriptions
where DATEDIFF(day, SUB_End , getdate()) <= 3;
```